# Executing config:cache command during deployment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I have a secret test key for a payment gateway in the `.env` file.

```
APP_TIMEZONE = 'Africa/Lagos'
APP_PAYSTACK_KEY = sk_test_b6c0b4925403blablabla
```

Reason is that other people working on the project can use their own test key if they have. So in a payment controller i get the value of this key like so:

```
"authorization: Bearer " .env('APP_PAYSTACK_KEY' , 'sk_test_b6c0b4925403blablabla')
```

During deployment I intend running `config:cache` so that Laravel won't be going a long trip in getting the required configuration setups. But from Laravel documentation :

> If you execute the config:cache command during your deployment
>   process, you should be sure that you are only calling the `env`
>   function from within your configuration files. Once the configuration
>   has been cached, the `.env` file will not be loaded and all calls to
>   the `env` function will return null.

So my question is how can I set this `APP_PAYSTACK_KEY` in the config file and how to retrieve it anywhere in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `paystack` to your `config/services.php` file:

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Third Party Services
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This file is for storing the credentials for third party services such
    | as Stripe, Mailgun, SparkPost and others. This file provides a sane
    | default location for this type of information, allowing packages
    | to have a conventional place to find your various credentials.
    |
    */

    // ...

    'paystack' => [
        'key' => env('APP_PAYSTACK_KEY', 'sk_test_b6c0b4925403blablabla'),
    ],
];
```

Then call `config()` helper method instead of `env()` on your controller:

```php
"authorization: Bearer " .config('services.paystack.key')
```

Now you're safe to cache your configs via calling `php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: Thanks for explaining better than the documentation (which doesn't at all) the benefits that using `config()` has over `env()`, I've always wondered this.